# OrientDB won't start after upgrade. Cannot create user guest: role guest does not exist

Tags: orientdb

When upgrading Orient DB server from 3.0 to 3.2, the server won't start after running ./server.sh due the following error:

```
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OCommandExecutionException: Cannot create user guest: role guest does not exist
        DB name="OSystem"
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.parser.OCreateSystemUserStatement.lambda$executeSimple$0(OCreateSystemUserStatement.java:99)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.OSystemDatabase.executeWithDB(OSystemDatabase.java:197)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.parser.OCreateSystemUserStatement.executeSimple(OCreateSystemUserStatement.java:48)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.executor.OSingleOpServerExecutionPlan.executeInternal(OSingleOpServerExecutionPlan.java:65)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.parser.OSimpleExecServerStatement.execute(OSimpleExecServerStatement.java:49)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.parser.OServerStatement.execute(OServerStatement.java:72)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.OrientDBEmbedded.executeServerStatement(OrientDBEmbedded.java:1255)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.OrientDB.execute(OrientDB.java:364)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer.createDefaultServerUsers(OServer.java:1058)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer.loadUsers(OServer.java:904)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer.activate(OServer.java:478)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServerMain$1.run(OServerMain.java:49)
```

Orient DB config file orientdb-server-config.xml has the following users added:

```
 <users>
         <user resources="*" password="{PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256}.." name="root"/>
        <user resources="connect,server.listDatabases,server.dblist" password="{PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256}.." name="guest"/>
    </users>
```

Presumably, a guest role needs to be created for the server to start. However, how does one create this role when the server cannot be started?

Answer (score 0):

in 3.2 there is a new auto creation of server users in the OSystem database, that from your error seems having migrating from OSystem databases created with 3.0.x, if you do not have settings in OSystem you can delete it (just delete the folder OSystem in the databases folder), the server on restart will recreate it with all the correct settings.

Feel free to open an issue on the issue tracker this seems a migration issue.